# Installation problems

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am using an Acer Aspire 4935G on Ubuntu 13.04 But I cannot install Ros Hydro, Can Someone please help me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/114916/installation-problems/) by [Ludwig](https://answers.ros.org/users/10486/ludwig/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-01-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) on 2014-01-05**:
what kind of error you recieved?

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2014-01-05**:
Hello, can you edit your question with more details about the installation process used and (as mentioned above) what specific error messages you observed?

**Comment by [Ludwig](https://answers.ros.org/users/10486/ludwig/) on 2014-01-06**:
I first tried to run it on 12.04. I copy the source code for 12.04 in but it said there was missing packages when I tried to update. I tried it on 13.04 but I got the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you compiling from source? Compiling from source is not for the faint of heart...have you tried the Debian packages following the instructions at http://wiki.ros.org/hydro/Installation/Ubuntu ?

---

Originally posted by [Tim Sweet](https://answers.ros.org/users/5998/tim-sweet/) with karma: 267 on 2014-01-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0